# CodeIgniter Query Missing Space

Tags: codeigniter

Any idea why my query from CodeIgniter is missing some space?

```
SELECT * FROM (`ddi_view_article_all`) WHERE LCASE(path_category)
```

Comment: Welcome to SOF. First of all, I will add more code around it ... Just the query is not enough. Now `WHERE LCASE(path_category)` will always return TRUE ... It's like doing `SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1;` or not adding a where clause at all.

Answer (score 0):

The query should be something like this

```
SELECT * FROM yourTableName WHERE sth = sth
```

Comment: Did you got what he is asking for ?